# The same upsell products appear at any product page on magento ee 1.12.0 with FPC enabled

Tags: magento-enterprise, full-page-cache

I'm not 100% sure, but it seems like a bug in magento's built-in implementation of hole-punching for up-sell/related products.

I looked through the code and found that container for upsell/related products depends on customer session, but not on the currently viewed product.

Class responsible for upsell/related products caching called `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_CatalogProductList` and it extends `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Advanced_Quote`. This class (CatalogProductList) doesn't overwrite neither `_getCacheId` nor `_getAdditionalCacheId` methods. Thus this cache only depends on customer's session and because of that whenever any visitor visits the product page, which is not in the cache yet, magento rebuilds upsells block for that particular product and after that it is used on every product page for this customer.

As a temporary solution, I added below method into CatalogProductList class, and it fixed the issue. I know this is poor solution and I'm going to change that, but I wanted to ask if anybody had such issue and what is the solution for it.

Method which was added is

```
public function applyWithoutApp(&$content)
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a patch fix for this. Ask support.

Comment: It's SUPEE-4092 that should help resolve this issue.

Comment: They will have to open a ticket with Magento to get an EE patch